# Transition to Octane: replace addObserver design

Tags: ember.js

Service requests performed by a service currently trigger "notifications" that components listen to using addObserver pattern ie the aService just toggles its _property and components act on it using aService.addObserver('_property'){action...}. How can I redesign this pattern in Octane, please? Thank you. Karel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For situations like these, I find it's useful to use [Ember.Evented](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Evented) and the pub/sub pattern.

The components use dependency injection to receive an instance of the service and in their constructor (or elsewhere if needed), they subscribe to some "topic" on the service. Consider an example where a `publisher` service generates ticks at a consistent interval. In our component, we want to subscribe to the `updateTick` topic and increment our current `tick` value each time the event is triggered.

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { inject } from '@ember/service';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';

export default class extends Component {
  @inject
  publisher;
  
  @tracked
  tick = 0;
  
  constructor(){
    super(...arguments);
    this.publisher.on('updateTick', () => {
      this.tick = this.tick + 1;
    });    
  }
}
```

When that topic has an updated value, the service then triggers an event that all subscribers can see. Here, I trigger an `updateTick` event every second.

```
import Service from '@ember/service';
import Evented from '@ember/object/evented';

export default class Publisher extends Service.extend(Evented){
  constructor(){
    super(...arguments);
    setInterval(() => { 
      this.trigger("updateTick");
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Here is the [example Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/335429a41ef448763ede1f29603ae4b8?openFiles=controllers.application%5C.js%2Ctemplates.components.subscriber%5C.hbs)

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much for this great help! I actually do use Evented already, but I thought it would be an overkill for this scenario. I have possibly misused the observer pattern before and will correct it using Evented. Exciting!